# How can I filter data before creating a graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Right now, I have this- I'm measuring the number of rides against rideable_type, which can either be classic_bike or electric_bike. However, this is for all user types. There is a column member_casual which denotes whether a user is a member or a casual user.

```
all_trips_v2 %>% 
  mutate(weekday = wday(started_at, label = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(member_casual, weekday, rideable_type) %>% 
  summarise(number_of_rides = n()
            ,average_duration = mean(ride_length)) %>% 
  arrange(member_casual, weekday)  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = weekday, y = number_of_rides , fill = rideable_type)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image: picture of graph]

I would like to filter member_casual to create a graph that would measure number of rides against rideable_type for only casuals, and another graph for members. How can I do this? Thanks.

edit:

```
dput(head(all_trips_v2, n=20))
structure(list(ride_id = c("C809ED75D6160B2A", "DD59FDCE0ACACAF3", 
"0AB83CB88C43EFC2", "7881AC6D39110C60", "853FA701B4582BAF", "F5E63DFD96B2A737", 
"C884951E36656727", "48B60B250FE75AF9", "E3D0CC2FE1359880", "4382735758ABF2CE", 
"2D3603B152699996", "45E714802D90545E", "FBC539FBC5314A71", "0E45FD9D4A607EB1", 
"99DEC758A46EE158", "7987674BCD95D7C1", "2E8574B3B98F8509", "3D9900961E27C1A0", 
"01EE40E8B8AFE1FD", "1439B3BB23FD8752"), rideable_type = c("electric_bike", 
"electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike", 
"electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike", 
"electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike", 
"electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike", 
"electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike"), started_at = structure(c(1622375895, 
1622374154, 1622384641, 1622384751, 1622398539, 1622374421, 1622371897, 
1620223023, 1620214286, 1620157865, 1620230855, 1622420801, 1622478093, 
1622412518, 1622423001, 1622485008, 1622475799, 1621964993, 1621896688, 
1621903933), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    ended_at = structure(c(1622376639, 1622376849, 1622384713, 
    1622385664, 1622398952, 1622375837, 1622372780, 1620224098, 
    1620214443, 1620159446, 1620231704, 1622421186, 1622478528, 
    1622413416, 1622423559, 1622487381, 1622476156, 1621966814, 
    1621897266, 1621905067), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), start_lat = c(41.9, 41.88, 41.92, 41.92, 41.94, 
    41.88, 41.93, 41.78, 41.78, 41.78, 41.78, 41.91, 41.93, 41.78, 
    41.78, 41.78, 41.91, 41.79, 41.92, 41.93), start_lng = c(-87.63, 
    -87.62, -87.7, -87.7, -87.69, -87.63, -87.7, -87.64, -87.64, 
    -87.64, -87.64, -87.65, -87.63, -87.64, -87.64, -87.64, -87.62, 
    -87.59, -87.71, -87.71), end_lat = c(41.89, 41.79, 41.92, 
    41.94, 41.94, 41.89, 41.9, 41.78, 41.78, 41.78, 41.78, 41.92, 
    41.93, 41.78, 41.78, 41.78, 41.9011315, 41.77, 41.93, 41.91
    ), end_lng = c(-87.61, -87.58, -87.7, -87.69, -87.7, -87.62, 
    -87.69, -87.64, -87.64, -87.64, -87.64, -87.64, -87.63, -87.64, 
    -87.64, -87.64, -87.6236296666667, -87.61, -87.71, -87.68
    ), member_casual = c("casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", 
    "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", 
    "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", 
    "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual"), date = structure(c(18777, 
    18777, 18777, 18777, 18777, 18777, 18777, 18752, 18752, 18751, 
    18752, 18778, 18778, 18777, 18778, 18778, 18778, 18772, 18771, 
    18772), class = "Date"), month = c("05", "05", "05", "05", 
    "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", 
    "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05"), day = c("30", "30", 
    "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "05", "05", "04", "05", "31", 
    "31", "30", "31", "31", "31", "25", "24", "25"), year = c("2021", 
    "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
    "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
    "2021", "2021", "2021"), day_of_week = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
    )), ride_length = c(744, 2695, 72, 913, 413, 1416, 883, 1075, 
    157, 1581, 849, 385, 435, 898, 558, 2373, 357, 1821, 578, 
    1134)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Try e.g. `... %>% filter(member_casual == ...) %>% ggplot(...)` or perhaps facet by `member_casual` using `+ facet_wrap(~ member_casual)`.

Comment: @Quinten Just added first 20 rows.